# failed to apply patch updating android studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio

updating android studio 141.2288178 to 141.2456560

below is the error log

```
java.io.IOException: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at com.intellij.updater.Digester.doDigestStream(Digester.java:76)
at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestStream(Digester.java:69)
at com.intellij.updater.Digester.digestRegularFile(Digester.java:21)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.digestFile(Patch.java:371)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.isModified(PatchAction.java:180)
at com.intellij.updater.DeleteAction.validate(DeleteAction.java:29)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch$1.forEach(Patch.java:271)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:360)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.validate(Patch.java:267)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.prepareAndValidate(PatchFileCreator.java:68)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.doInstall(Runner.java:293)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.access$000(Runner.java:18)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner$2.execute(Runner.java:261)
at com.intellij.updater.SwingUpdaterUI$5.run(SwingUpdaterUI.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

updating android studio

[image]

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I just switched to Ubuntu instead of Windows

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not the answer you were looking for but if you are still struggeling to update Android Studio I would recommend to update it from the website:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Android Studio will detect settings from older versions and prompt you to import them on first run.

Comment: I am on a slow connection. Patch size is 36 Mb and full zip package is 350 MB+. Still thanks for suggestion.